# do some operation only for active tabitem in Prism

Tags: wpf, shell, prism, eventaggregator

i develop application using prism have tabcontrol in the shell with 5 tabitem and combox i want to do some operation when combox selected item change on only active tabitem 
how to do this with Event Aggregator ?

Comment: when selected combobox item is changed on current tab, why will the event be raised for other tabs? Can you show us some code as to where you're facing a problem?

Comment: the combox exits out of tab control contained in the shell so it will be shared between all tabitems

Comment: Please add some code.